# Can I use Act of Aggression to steal their attacking creature and block with it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent declares two creatures as attackers. I want to play [Act of Aggression](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230076) to gain control of one of their creatures and so I can have it block their other creature. Is this possible? Is so, during what step do I need to play my Act of Aggression? If I played it during my declare blockers step, would the creature that I now controlled still be attacking me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  You would play the spell during the declare attackers step, after attackers are declared, but before proceeding to the declare blockers step.  Then you are free to declare it as a blocker.  If you wait for your declare blockers step, it's too late to block with the creature.

The ordering is:

- Declare Attackers Starts:
- Turn Based Action - Attackers are declared
- Players get Priority <- Cast Spell Now!
- Declare Blockers Starts:
- Turn Based Action - Blockers are declared
- Players get Priority <- Too late
  to use as blocker if cast now!

Any time a creature changes controllers, it is automatically removed from combat, so it will no longer be considered attacking you (or attacking/blocking at all if it previously was).